# Parse.com Node js failed to load json file

Tags: node.js, express, parse-platform

I'm trying to read a json file using node js/ express and deploying it to parseCloud but i keep getting

*Failed to load filters.json with: Could not find file filters.json *

here is my code:

```html
var fs = require('fs');
var obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('cloud/filters.json', 'utf8'));
```

or this

```html
var filterJson = require('cloud/filters.json');
```

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Looks like parse.com doesn't allow `.json` files. You can save your file as `.js` and load it as plain text file (doesn't work with `require()`).

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var parsedObject = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('cloud/path/json_file.js'));
```

It looks ugly, but works for me. :)

Answer (score -1):

Try to add `./`

```
fs.readFileSync('./cloud/filters.json', 'utf8')
```

Comment: Invalid file path: ./cloud/filters.json path must start with cloud/